# Why the value of a variable is not entering post_content on just one occasion?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, cron

I have a file of autoimport.php

```
    $identif = (string)$numbz;
    $myembed = (string)$feed_item->embed;
    $feed_item->desc .= "{$identif}{$myembed}<br>{$feed_item->desc}";
$post = array(
        'post_author'     => '1',
        'post_status'     => $_POST['status'],
        'post_type'       => $cpt,
        'post_title'      => (string)$feed_item->title,
        'post_content'    => (string)$feed_item->desc,
        );
    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post );
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'sponsor',  (string)$_POST['thelink']);
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'contID',  (string)$feed_item->id);
```

There are two variables that I add in post_content in the publish action, always right with manual posting, but when the plugin uses another file to do the import of the post, to trigger the post, this variable $myembed does not enter at all in post_content. Why does it happen?
I make the change in the two files, all right in the manual post.
Importmanual.php has a code almost the same as above, with difference that use post_args:

```
$post_args = array(
          'post_author'     => '1',
          'post_status'     => $status,
          'post_type'       => $tca,
          'post_title'      => (string)$ivd['title'],
          'post_content'    => (string)$ivd['desc'],
        );

$post_id = wp_insert_post( $post_args );
```

And the names of the variables are other, but I copy and paste, there is no writing error. Include the idea is so correct that the code works and the $identif variable comes together perfectly, what could it be?

see them complete: manual post file and auto post file Within the documents search for: ‘hercules’ and you will see a short explanation before the code. https://pastebin.com/s9Xcibd6

Comment: tried using wp_query?

Comment: Hello @ste thanks for reply, please see the two files here: https://pastebin.com/s9Xcibd6